# Javascript Object : check every object in array of object where value equal to

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, methods, iteration

Please find below general problematic regarding object iteration and queries.

Here is an object list (aimed at managing a connexion form) :

```
const connexionData = {
  mail: {
    value: false,
    isRequired: true
  },
  password: {
    value: false,
    isRequired: true
  },
  name: {
    value: false,
    isRequired: false
  },
}
```

Here is an array variable which stores all the object from `connexionData` 
`const fieldstocheck = [connexionData.mail, connexionData.password, connexionData.name]`

And the purpose of the function `check` below is to check if:

For each object in `fieldstocheck` where  `isRequired` is true, if `value` is false, return true, or else, return false

```
const check = () => {
  if((fieldstocheck.filter(key => 
    key.isRequired).every(val => 
        !val.value))) {
            return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

This function does the job in general. With current object values, it returns `true`, and `false` if `values` are changed to `true` or to `""`

But I was wondering if there would be a faster or mor elegant way of reaching the same goal.

and, yes, have a nice day everyone

Comment: Does it work? If yes, then it's offtopic here and belongs to https://codereview.stackoverflow.com If no, what problems are you seeing? And please refrain from extensively using **bold** it makes the question hard to read (especially if improperly used and mixed with other markups)

Comment: do you need the if else what happens if just return `fieldstocheck.filter(key => 
    key.isRequired).every(val => 
        !val.value)`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a code review question, and probably belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Note: [read their help section first](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you're after is a boolean, but you're currently using `.filter()` which creates an intermediate array. You can remove the `.filter()` and instead call `.every()` directly on `fieldstocheck` array to avoid creating a new array in memory. Removing the filter also does fewer iterations as you're only iterating your array once:

```js
const connexionData = { mail: { value: false, isRequired: true }, password: { value: false, isRequired: true }, name: { value: false, isRequired: false }, }

const fieldstocheck = [connexionData.mail, connexionData.password, connexionData.name];

const res = fieldstocheck.every((obj) => !obj.isRequired || !obj.value);
console.log(res);
```

In the above, we first check if `isRequired` is `false` with `!obj.isRequired`. If it is `false` then the `.every()` callback method returns `true` for that object (as we're negating `!` `isRequired`). When the first operand for `||` is truthy, the `||` short-ciruits and so we don't worry about checking right-hand side of the `||`. Otherwise, if `isRequired` is `true`, we check the right-hand side of the condition to check if the `obj.value` is false: `!obj.value`.

In propsitonal logic, the above condition:

```
!obj.isRequired || !obj.value
```

is logically equivalent to

```
!(obj.isRequired && obj.value)
```

(see [De Morgan's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) for more details), so we could have also used this as our condition also. You could interpret this as: if the object is required and has a value, then return `false`, otherwise, `true` (if it isn't required or doesn't have a value).